# Does anyone remember prophecy of beast with thousand names or possible Mandela effect?

Tags: eschatology, prophecy, antichrist, identify-this, beast

I have a memory of reading about end times prophecy that talks about beast with thousand names and at that time I thought that now when people have lot of nicknames and usernames on internet, maybe somebody can have thousand usernames.
But now when I try to Google this with different search words, I cannot find it. Is this a Mandela effect or do I just remember incorrectly or is the prophecy so obscure that it cannot be found on the internet?

Does anyone else remember this prophecy about the beast or antichrist?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange! You'll have to provide a lot more information about this in order for us to answer it. When did you read this? Where did you read it (print, online, etc)? Do you remember anything about the author? Was it affiliated with any Christian groups? Were there any other points the author was trying to make? As is, there isn't enough information to answer this. Also, without knowing exactly what it was you saw, we can't really judge whether this is a "[Mandela effect](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-mandela-effect)" false memory.

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember at all where I heard it but it must have been during years 2003-2010 and I cannot say anything about the source because I found Christianity again only recently.

Comment: The Hindu deity Vishnu has 1000 names. God, in Islam, is sometimes said to have 99 names, and there is an idea that having 100 names would be to exalt oneself above God.  I wonder if either of these may have influenced your memory.  Between 2003 to 2010 did you read Biblical Commentaries, books on theology and eschatology, books of the genre of Dan Brown, or all of these. Internet, church bookstall, public library  etc.or all?.  Even though you do not recall the author are there genres we can rule out?

Comment: No. During those years I was not interested in religion at all. I have never read Dan Brown. I read Lovecraft, Wikipedia, Listverse and such. It would be helpful to rule out some genres but I don't think it possible because during those years I spend lot of time in the weird part of the internet. At that time there were lot of small website and blogs.  asked this question at some other message board and somebody answered to me that they also remember that. Weird. But this is not the first time I vividly remember reading something on the internet and later don't find it again.

Answer (score 5):

I've heard the phrase before.  There is no reference in the Bible that states it or that can even construe it.  However, the idea is popular in some end-times circles.  It almost always refers to Nimrod of the Old testament.  For example:

- The book, *[The Beast Who Once Was: New Insight into End Times Prophecy](https://books.google.com/books?id=zImUBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=bible+%22end+times%22+beast+%22thousand+names%22&source=bl&ots=EtUVO1m4RH&sig=7zCUtD4f4NnGpSonzxIvgyBG_Yg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx3YDNr6jdAhXL1IMKHZWIBpIQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=bible%20%22end%20times%22%20beast%20%22thousand%20names%22&f=false)* 
  by Chris Relitz refers to Revelation 17:8 to identify the beast that "once was, now is not, and yet will come," identifying the "beast that once was" as Nimrod from the Old Testament and describing him as "the god with a thousand names."

This association is made because many associate Nimrod with various nationa/ethnic/religious gods of ancient times, inevitably ending with the Egyptian Osiris/Isis story.

Whether this is considered prophecy or not depends on which Christian denomination or tradition you adhere to.

Comment: That's interesting. That could be it. Although I remember it referring more clearly to the beast of revelation. I mean, if thousand names refers names in history given by different nations, then I would not think about usernames on internet.

Comment: There are several beasts mentioned in Revelation, this is the circumstance I'm familiar with.  Please bear in mind that any discussion linking a beast in Revalation with the Internet is remarkably modern (but it wouldn't surprise me for someone to try and make the connection).  Regrettably, this will also make the specific discussion very hard to find.  A lot of people like to speculate about the end-times.  The result is the Internet is flooded with stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mandella Affected misrememberation may have been attributed to the Gospel of Mark where Jesus is casting out a demon with a confusing name.

> He asked him, “What is your name?” He replied, “Legion is my name. There are many of us.
>
> [Mk 5:9 - NAB](https://www.usccb.org/bible/mk/5:9)

At least that's what my mind immediately came up with when reading your question.  "Beast" and "Devil" are pretty comparable in many people's minds. In any event, I think this is the only time a demon with a plurality of names is mentioned in the Bible and it may be the source of whatever it is you're looking for.